# Why do I get an error when using LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, load-data-infile, mysql-error-1045

I'm trying to use `SQL` to upload a `csv` file from my laptop to a database, however I get a strange error. The code I am typing into the SQL window in phpMyAdmin is as follows:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/myMac/testServerUpload.csv' 
INTO TABLE `testDatabase` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error

SQL query:

LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/myMac/testServerUpload.csv' INTO TABLE `testDatabase` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

MySQL said: Documentation
#1045 - Access denied for user 'ukld'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

Should I be using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` instead of my current command as the file is on my computer? Both give me an error, and I thought `LOCAL` might mean that it is on the server. I could not find relevant advice searching for this error.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and fixed it by using LOCAL and giving the full file path:

```
'C:/directory/file.csv'
```

It seems the 1045 error comes from not having access to files on the *server*, which is where mySQL looks for the file if LOCAL is not specified.

See also:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlimport.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to login as root and run:

`SHOW GRANTS FOR 'ukld'@'%';`

Chances are you don't have the permissions that you think you do...you need INSERT privileges on the db and table(s) into which you are trying to `LOAD DATA`.

---

**UPDATE:**

To correct the GRANT issue, run these statements ***as root*** in your MySQL install:

```
REVOKE SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE,
       DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,
       LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW,
       CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE
       ON ukld.* FROM 'ukld'@'%';

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE,
       DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,
       LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW,
       CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE
       ON ukld.* TO 'ukld'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxx';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Make sure you set the correct password in the second statement.

Comment: @AJ I tried that with the following results: `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'ukld'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxx'
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `ukld`.* TO 'ukld'@'%'
`

Comment: Looks like that second GRANT statement is missing the `IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxx'` part...

Comment: hmmm. It is my database, and I can manually import a csv file into it. Is there some way I can enter my password when I run this line of `SQL`?

Comment: It's not a matter of **entering** a password.  Look at the error - it says:  "using password: YES" meaning you ARE providing a password (but it's not being accepted by the system).  What you need to do is update the GRANTS for the second set of privileges so that it includes your password.  I'll update my answer to show you how to do this.

Comment: @AJ Thanks for your help. I ran the statement you wrote with the correct password but got an error message `#1044 - Access denied for user 'ukld'@'%' to database 'ukld'`

Comment: You got the error running the GRANT statement, or after you ran the GRANT statement when you re-tried your LOAD DATA operation?

Comment: Ah, well you need to run it as root :)  Sorry if I didn't emphasize that point.

Comment: hmmm, still no luck. I don't know how to use commands to mover around phpMyAdmin, so I just clicked on to the highest level of the file browser, and ran the SQL from there. I got the same error message.

Comment: Do you have access to the command line?  If so, you should be able to run: `mysql -u root -Ppassword -h hostname`  This will log you in as root and then you can finish up the GRANT statements.

Comment: I'm not sure how to access the DB via a mac terminal. I'll look into what options are available.